# PHP yii2 dataProvider get TotalCount and export to Excel

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, pdo, yii2

I want to export all data from my MySQL database using the following code:

```
public function actionExport()
{
return $this->createDatAndRen('export', false);
}


private function createDatAndRen($view, $setPagi = true)
{
    $searchModel = new ASearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    $paginat = new Pagination(['pageSize' => $setPagi ? 50 : $dataProvider->getTotalCount()]);
    $dataProvider->paginat = $paginat;

    return $this->render($view, [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dpro' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

If I click the export button I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: Tried to bind parameter number 2101. SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters.

My problem is if getTotalCount() = 50 or 1000 I can read all of the output. But if I have 3049 items, I can not export it to excel.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to [issue#10371](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/10371):

> MSSQL has a hard limit in a number of parameters you can pass to stored procedure. And it looks like Yii2 uses stored procedures to prepare SQL statement.

MySQL and Oracle too have that limit.

One solution can be to increase that limit, which is not recommended (and i didn't find anyone recommending to do so).

Another solution is, when you hit the limit divide your query in chunk of, lets say 2000 records and do multiple query to fetch your data.